mongoDB - can't connect when db name specified
I can't connect to mongoDB started in a container when database path is specified. I use mongoDB Compass to test connection - it returns Authentication failed.
The container with mongo is started via docker compose up and here are compose.yaml contents:
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: "mongo"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: mongoadmin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: a12345
    volumes:
      - './db-data/mongodb:/data/db'
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

After starting the container I connect with connection string:
mongodb://mongoadmin:a12345@localhost:27017

then I create db named sampledb. When I  modify connection string to point to it directly connection fails:
mongodb://mongoadmin:a12345@localhost:27017/sampledb

(without /sampledb it connects).
Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Try adding the authSource to the connection string. E.g.,
mongodb://mongoadmin:a12345@localhost:27017/sampledb?authSource=admin


Please use below connection string

"mongodb://user:pwd@hostname/myDB?authSource=admin" -- authentication database is admin and current database would be myDB
"mongodb://user:pwd@hostname?authSource=admin"   -- authentication database is admin and current database would be the test

